# Android Restlet 404 Error Not Foun

Tags: android, rest, http-status-code-404, restlet

I'm doing a rest client for android and using [restlet](http://www.restlet.org).

So, when I run my app I get 404 Error - Not Found when trying to store my data. My is up and running normal.

```
 package com.example.app;

 import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

 import android.util.Log;

 import com.example.app.models.Accounts;
 import com.example.app.models.AccountsResource;

 public class ServerConection {

    private AccountsResource resource;

        public ServerConection(){

        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/accounts/");
        resource = cr.wrap(AccountsResource.class);
    }

    public void send(Accounts account){
        resource.store(account);    
    }

}


public interface AccountsResource {
    @Get
    public Accounts retrieve();

    @Put
    public void store(Accounts account);

    @Delete
    public void remove();
}
```

LogCat

```
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290): Not Found (404) - Not Found
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource$1.invoke(ClientResource.java:1663)
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at $Proxy4.store(Native Method)
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at com.example.app.ServerConection.send(ServerConection.java:26)
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at com.example.app.AccountIntentService.sendAccount(AccountIntentService.java:56)
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at com.example.app.AccountIntentService.access$1(AccountIntentService.java:55)
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at com.example.app.AccountIntentService$2.run(AccountIntentService.java:44)
10-18 19:55:12.658: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: What's happening on the server side?  Is that your code also, or do you have any logs from the server that would indicate what the issue might be?  What happens if you perform the HTTP request with another tool, like curl -- does that return a 404 also?

Comment: By the way, it's probably not related to your current problem, but I found it a little odd that you have a parameter "account" (singular) of type Accounts (plural).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the logs for the server side application, it is possible that you've got the URL wrong in your application.

As Andy mentioned in his comment with account/s, are you sure the URL might not be `http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/account/` (singular) instead?

Double check the URL, if the problem still isn't resolved then we'd need to see the server logs.